# iOS Hover effect on UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a Login-button on my UIView.
I will have a click-effect or more likely a hover-effect (I know hovering isnt possible on a iOS Device, but you know, it should be looking nice).

The button should change the image on hover / click.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set the hover image for the highlighted state:

```
[button setImage:hoverImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```